# How may I center on table in Gdocs (table import from Gsheet with appendTable())

Tags: google-apps-script

Could you tell me how to put my table in the CENTER of a page of Gdocs (table imported from Gsheet with appendTable()).

My table has several rows and columns. Right now, this small table stick on the left of the page.

Here is code for 2 columns and several rows :

```
table = body.appendTable(srcData).setColumnWidth(0, 200).setColumnWidth(1, 22); 
table.editAsText().setFontSize(10).setBold(true) ;}
```